# $f'(a) \gt 0$ and $f'$ is continuous at $a$, then there $I_a$ where f is increasing.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives, continuity

I have a little problem with a proof, I managed to get to a result, but I think I got there committing some mistakes.

So, i have to prove that if

- $f'(a) \gt 0$
- $f'$ is continuous at $a$

Then

$f$ is increasing in some interval containing $a$

So i can say there is an interval where $f'$ is positive using the intermediate value theorem for continuous functions, as it is also said in this other [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2745577/a-continuously-differentiable-function-with-positive-derivative-at-a-point-is-in):

But i don't know how to rigorously say $f$ is increasing in the interval:

I think i can use the definition of derivative:

$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h} \gt 0$$

Then it follows:

$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(a+h)}{h} \gt \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a)}{h}$$

Case $h \gt 0$

$$\lim_{h\to 0} f(a+h) \gt \lim_{h\to 0}f(a)$$

Case $h \lt 0$

$$\lim_{h\to 0} f(a+h) \lt \lim_{h\to 0}f(a)$$

I choose $b = a +h$ and then I have $$\lim_{b\to a} f(b) \gt \lim_{b\to a}f(a)$$

Is that sufficient to end the proof?

As last point I have to prove that the continuity of $f'$ at $a$ is essential, but I can't understand that... If I proceed with the defintion of derivative alone, can't I show that there is at least an interval (for
how small it could be) containing $a$ where "f" is increasing proceeding as I did before?

That's the reason because I think that the way I approached the problem is not correct.

Comment: I am not sure about your hypothesis. Do you mena $f'(a)>0$ and $f'$ continuous at $a$?

Comment: You can not break up the limit as you did.

Comment: For your last part, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2768994/differentiable-at-a-point-with-positive-derivative-implies-increasing-in-neighbo).

Comment: Use MVT for the first part (after observing $f'>0$ on some open interval containing $a$).

Answer (score 1):

Knowing there is an interval $I_a$ surrounding $a$ where $f' > 0$.  To show $f$ is increasing on $I_a$.  The rigorous way to do this is the *Mean Value Theorem*.  Let $u, v \in I_a$, $u<v$.  Note $f$ is continuous on $[u,v]$, differentiable on $(u,v)$.  By the MVT there is $w$ with $u < w < v$ where
$$
\frac{f(v)-f(u)}{v-u} = f'(w)
$$
thus
$$
\frac{f(v)-f(u)}{v-u} > 0\qquad\text{so}\qquad f(v)-f(u) > 0 .
$$

Answer (score 0):

I will give a hint that if $f'(a)=u > 0 $ then using the same continuity argument you used to find an interval where the derivative is positive you can restrict the interval you choose a little more so that $f'(x)>\frac{u}{2}>0$ on the interval.

The next steps will depend on what techniques you are allowed to use without proof.

Certainly if you can use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus and comparison results the solution will follow quickly from there.